# Configuring jmx_exporter with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jmx, hikaricp, mbeans, jmx-exporter

I am trying to expose some of my spring application metrics (Spring). The metrics are mainly database connection metrics. To do so, I started by configuring a hikari connection pool, then I used jmx. To export the metrics to prometheus then visiualize them with Grafana, I tried to used jmx_prometheus_exporter [https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter][1]

I downlaoded the jmx_exporter jar and then I added this line in my Tomcat8 service (in the folder init.d)

> export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS
>   -javaagent:/home/monitoring/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=9095:/home/monitoring/config-jmx-tomcat.yaml"

This the config file file for tomcat (config-jmx-tomcat.yaml)

```
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true lowercaseOutputName: true rules:
- pattern: 'Catalina<type=GlobalRequestProcessor, name=\"(\w+-\w+)-(\d+)\"><>(\w+):'   name: tomcat_$3_total   labels:
    port: "$2"
    protocol: "$1"   help: Tomcat global $3   type: COUNTER
- pattern: 'Catalina<j2eeType=Servlet, WebModule=//([-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:.,;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]), name=([-a-zA-Z0-9+/$%~_-|!.]*), J2EEApplication=none, J2EEServer=none><>(requestCount|maxTime|processingTime|errorCount):'   name: tomcat_servlet_$3_total   labels:
    module: "$1"
    servlet: "$2"   help: Tomcat servlet $3 total   type: COUNTER
- pattern: 'Catalina<type=ThreadPool, name="(\w+-\w+)-(\d+)"><>(currentThreadCount|currentThreadsBusy|keepAliveCount|pollerThreadCount|connectionCount):' name: tomcat_threadpool_$3   labels:
    port: "$2"
    protocol: "$1"   help: Tomcat threadpool $3   type: GAUGE
- pattern: 'Catalina<type=Manager, host=([-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:.,;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]), context=([-a-zA-Z0-9+/$%~_-|!.]*)><>(processingTime|sessionCounter|rejectedSessions|expiredSessions):' name: tomcat_session_$3_total   labels:
    context: "$2"
    host: "$1"   help: Tomcat session $3 total   type: COUNTER
```

In my application This is how I define the connection pool and MbeanServer....

```
MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName poolName = new ObjectName("com.zaxxer.hikari:type=Pool (foo)");
HikariPoolMXBean poolProxy = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mBeanServer, poolName, HikariPoolMXBean.class);
int idleConnections = poolProxy.getIdleConnections();
```

When I try to acceed to localhost:9095/metrics, I find nothing, and the catalina logs, tomcat logs, show nothing.

My questions are:

- Are the steps that I am following are correct or not?
- How can I debug or where should I see the errors?
- I keep finding tutorials showing conifgs with jmx remote . When to use this ? 
  thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: Any answer found for this ? I could see all the other metrics but not connectionpool metrics .. how did u resolve this issue ?